# Disable whatever :hover css effects there is when on a different media

Tags: html, css

I'm not sure if this is even possible, but I'd like to throw it out there: say I have something like

```
.this-thing:hover {
  /* something magical */
}
```

in CSS. During Print Preview and Print, I would like to "disable" whatever hover effect is on `.this-thing`, such that even if the user is hovering over a given element when they decide they want to print the page, the effects from `/* something magical */` do not appear on Print Preview or the printed media.

Is there a pure CSS solution to this?

Note that I do not want to found out what the specifics of `/* something magical */` is in order to disable it during `@media print`.

Comment: It seems so odd to me that the print styles would inherit the hover rules! I did a quick test and it definitely shows up in the print preview. Interesting Q!

Answer (score 1):

You could use `@media only screen` to apply the hover effects only to the `:hover` rules.

So you would do:

```
@media only screen {
    .this-thing:hover {
      /* something magical */
    }
}
```

Organizationally, this may be a mess to pepper `@media only screen` around all of your hovers, but it's one option.

Answer (score 1):

The same way as you use the `only` and `and` logical selector, you can use the `not` to specify that the style rule should not apply to some media type:

```
@media not print {
    .this-thing:hover {
        /* something magical */
    }
}
```